# How to sort the merged arrays in php?

Tags: php

I have two arrays

using array_merge function, merged two arrays. Then I need to sort the merged array.

This is my php code

```
<?php
$file=file("master.bib");
$c=count($file);


//count of article
$key = '@article';
foreach ($file as $l => $line) {
    if (strpos($line,$key) !== false) {
       $l++;
       $typeart[]= $l;

          }
}//end-count of article

$key = '}';
foreach ($file as $l => $line) {
    if (strpos($line,$key) === 0) {
       $l++;
       $typeclose[]= $l;

          }
}



$p=array_merge($typeart,$typeclose);
echo sort($p);
?>
```

But am getting the output 1. I don't know what's wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see from the [`sort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) documentation, your array is a [*reference*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php).

```
bool sort ( array &$array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR ] )
//                ^ & means reference
```

This means that your *original* array will be changed when the method is run. As you can also see by the documentation, it returns the following:

> Returns `TRUE` on success or `FALSE` on failure.

So essentially (just like the example in the documentation) the correct use is:

```
sort($p); // $p will now be sorted
```

or the more verbose

```
if (sort($p)) {
    // $p is now sorted
} else {
    // $p could not be sorted for whatever reason
}
```

Comment: sorry, I don't get it clearly. How can I store or echo the sorted output? Is there any wrong in my code?

Comment: @VidhyaRaju The value is already stored in `$p` (you did that when you merged them), and `sort` just *changes* `$p`. You print arrays by using [`print_r`](http://www.php.net/print_r): `print_r($p);`. If you print to HTML, use a `pre` tag: `echo '<pre>' . print_r($p, true) . '</pre>';`. You can also use the more verbose [`var_dump`](http://www.php.net/var_dump)

Answer (score 0):

`sort` changes your array directly, so you should use `print_r($p)` to check the array like this:

```
sort($p); //Array Sorted and contents changed directly no return :)

print_r($p);
```